# Symfony3 class inheritance and db relationships

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony

I have these 3 entitites

**Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Users
*
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
*/
class Users
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string")
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="feedback", type="integer")
 */
private $feedback;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="picture", type="blob")
 */
private $picture;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="integer", length=255)
 */
private $rating;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="info", type="text")
 */
private $info;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="datecreated", type="datetime")
 */
private $datecreated;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;
}
```

**client.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* client
*
* @ORM\Table(name="client")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\clientRepository")
*/
class client extends Users
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numberofjobsposted", type="integer")
 */
private $numberofjobsposted;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="clienttype", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $clienttype;
}
```

**sprovider.php**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* sprovider
*
* @ORM\Table(name="sprovider")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\sproviderRepository")
*/
class sprovider extends Users
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="interestedin", type="simple_array")
 */
private $interestedin;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numofsuccjobs", type="integer")
 */
private $numofsuccjobs;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sprovidertype", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $sprovidertype;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="postcode", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $postcode;
}
```

So I achieved that the `extends` statement provides the `Users` properties in the `client` and `sprovider` tables in MySQL. That's awesome. What I want now is to make the relations so that when I add a new `client` for example, both the tables `Users` and `client` add a new user/client in MySQL, and they have same `id` too.

the `type()` property in the `Users` entity i would like to be optional for the type of user I create. Example : I create a new `client` and in the `Users` table in MySQL the type is set to "CLIENT".

I read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) and so far I think it has to be ManyToMany relation but It's quite confusing to me.

How to make those relations in the entities and then how to use them in the controller? If possible, please provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confused about the reasons to use inheritance.

The idea is that you have base class, in this case User, and that can be extended to provide variations of that class, in this case `client` (you should **capitalise** this) and `sprovider`.

Ideally, you would not have a `User` table, only the other 2.

In doctrine, this is called a mapped super-class.

> A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, but which is not itself an entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.

see [the documentation here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

you can link properties using relationships, this is their example.

```
<?php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $mapped1;
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $mapped2;
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="MappedSuperclassRelated1")
     * @JoinColumn(name="related1_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $mappedRelated1;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** @Entity */
class EntitySubClass extends MappedSuperclassBase
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $name;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do here won't work because I'm using 2 register forms but only one login form. The form checks the `Users` table for match with the login credentials and if `email` and `password` match with an entry in this `Users` table, the login form redirects, depending on the `type()` of this entry in the table.

Comment: I would just build that into a custom user provider and keep a more standard data structure.

Comment: what do you mean by "custom user provider"

Comment: [custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html), this way you can get it to look in both tables for a user